# Android bluetooth socket cannot disconnect

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I'm working on a BluetoothChat sample based app, one device send another device parameters and the second send the  data. I think that problem is in Connected thread run() method which i must edit because the original version receive data in not correct order . If I close program running on one device the second device is still connected to disconnected device.

```
public void run() {
        int bytes;
        int availableBytes=0;

        while (true) {
            try {
                availableBytes=mmInStream.available();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[availableBytes];
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                   if (bytes>0){
                       mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                               .sendToTarget();
                   }

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity

            } catch (IOException e) {
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothClientService.this.start();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't restart threads. The way you are using `available()` is specifically warned against in the Javadoc.

Comment: Why cant restart threads ?.... problem is that exception is not thrown by i dont know why .